# How do I pass a file name with blank spaces as an argument in command line python ver 3

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-arguments, args

I have been trying this
python myscript.py filename.txt

print(args[1]) --> filename.txt - This is Ok

But when I want to try
python myscript.py file name.txt
print(args[1]) --> file -- I hope to take the full string "file name.txt"

Any idea?, Thanks a lot.

Comment: protect with quotes!!

Comment: `python myscript.py "file name.txt"`

Comment: Thanks a lot... I did it, and it works,,,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sys.argv arguments with spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37718580/sys-argv-arguments-with-spaces)