# How get specifics arguments in a string python

Tags: python, arguments

I have 3 arguments to give to my program but python recognizes more than 3.
Ex :

```
./myprogram "fist argument" "second argument" "thrid one"
```

So sys.argv[1] will be - "first and sys.argv[2] will be argument

How can I have 3 only strings?
like string1 = "fist argument" ect..

Comment: Are you actually passing them in as strings or have you added the quotes for your question here?

Comment: I pass them in strings

Comment: This is probably something to do with your shell. See https://bugs.python.org/issue10322

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments)

Comment: the problem with those solutions is: it's doing: string = "first arg second arg third arg".

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be using spaces for the argument, as it is the delimiter for command line arguments. Consider using quotes to enclose the argument, or, in a hacky way, for example, merge the first two strings to get the first argument, and so on.

Also, i believe this was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37718580/sys-argv-arguments-with-spaces/37718627).

Comment: If you believe this question already has an answer somewhere else, why do you post a new answer?

Comment: I will always receive args with spaces and I can't change it but thanks for your answer ;)

Comment: @RiccardoBucco Exactly because my answer, while based on another is a new one - if you consider the idea of posterior merging the arguments to be a new one, that is.