# PyPDF2 gives "TypeError: argument should be integer or None, not 'NullObject'"

Tags: python, windows, pdf, pypdf

With this script I'm going to create one single pdf file that combines the many pdfs in the
folder that I gave it in this line of code `input_folder_pdf = sys.argv[1]`from the terminal and it creates the output folder if not exists .
this code worked

```
import PyPDF2
import sys
import os
input_folder_pdf = sys.argv[1]
output_folder_file = sys.argv[2]
if not os.path.exists(output_folder_file):
    os.makedirs(output_folder_file)
    print(output_folder_file, 'folder crated!')
input_name = input('name the combined pdf : ')
pdf_inputs = []
for filename in os.listdir(input_folder_pdf):
    name = f'{input_folder_pdf}{filename}'
    pdf_inputs.append(name)
merger = PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger(strict=False)
for pdf in pdf_inputs:
    merger.append(pdf)
    print(pdf, ' added!!')
combined_name = str(output_folder_file) + str(input_name) + '.pdf'
merger.write(combined_name)
print('Done!')
```

I ran this code like this in the porwershell :
`python3.9.exe {this_script.py} {.\the_path_folder_of_the_pdfs\} {.\the_output_folder\}`
giving the folder name with spaces cause a problem with sys.argv[1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12kPaoYuGwC_8pi24ZwxKB6bLRYICkoGa/view?usp=sharing) index for me.

here link of files that works good with this code:
[folder of pdfs that works well with this code](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cjdK6th4nFEF4RHSO6L92lUlLjFN_49H?usp=sharing)

here is the link of files that cause this problem:
[pdf1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13LARJqUZJuldZdq2O1SaddFdxxlISiDw/view?usp=sharing)
[pdf2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12kPaoYuGwC_8pi24ZwxKB6bLRYICkoGa/view?usp=sharing)
this error happens :

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyPDF2\_reader.py:993: PdfReadWarning: Invalid stream (index 35) within object 96 0: Stream has ended unexpectedly
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\download telegram desktop\Manga\jujustu_kaisen\Pdf_combiner.py", line 22, in <module>
    merger.write(final_name)
  File"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PyPDF2\generic.py", line 800, in read_from_stream
    data["__streamdata__"] = stream.read(length)
TypeError: argument should be integer or None, not 'NullObject'
```

Comment: For filenames and directories with spaces: [sys.argv arguments with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37718580/sys-argv-arguments-with-spaces)

Comment: Sounds like a bug in PyPDF2. Worth reporting it there.

Answer (score 0):

Move from PyPDF2 to pypdf. I'm the maintainer of both projects and I no longer update PyPDF2.

The bug was still present in `pypdf==3.2.0` but is no longer in `pypdf==3.4.1`. **Upgrade your `pypdf` version**.

### How to ask good questions

As a side-note, the problematic parts of the code that showed the issue could have been reduced to:

```py
from pypdf import PdfMerger

merger = PdfMerger(strict=False)
merger.append("problematic-doc.pdf")
merger.write("out-combined.pdf")
```

A traceback with Python 3.11 would then look like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/moose/so-pypdf/foo.py", line 4, in <module>
    merger.append("problematic-doc.pdf")
  File "/home/moose/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pypdf/_utils.py", line 441, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/moose/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pypdf/_merger.py", line 317, in append
    self.merge(len(self.pages), fileobj, outline_item, pages, import_outline)
  File "/home/moose/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pypdf/_utils.py", line 441, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/moose/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pypdf/_merger.py", line 194, in merge
    stream, encryption_obj = self._create_stream(fileobj)
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/moose/.pyenv/versions/3.11.1/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pypdf/_merger.py", line 263, in _create_stream
    stream = FileIO(fileobj, "rb")
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'problematic-doc.pdf'
```